# How to fake Windows Version in Wine

Tags: kubuntu, wine

I am trying to install this software [Xerox device agent](https://www.support.xerox.com/en-gb/product/smart-esolutions/content/117250?language=en&platform=winxp) to my Kubuntu. So far I followed the standard steps:

1. I installed `wine64` (version 5.0) together with `winetricks` from the Ubuntu repository.
2. I installed the `mono` package from the [Wine website](https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/5.0.0/).
3. In `winecfg` I set the Windows version to WINDOWS 10 for my application.
4. I attempted to start the installer, but I got the following error message:

   ```
   The host is not running a supported Windows operating system version.
   ```
5. I tried some other Windows versions but with no change.

My questions are:

1. Can I somehow debug what this application is trying to read to get the Windows version?
2. Is there still another way how to fake the Windows version?

**UPDATE 05.01.2021**
Here is the error I see after execution:

```
0009:err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"DM: Error in Remove XP support System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: ptr\r\n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(intptr)\r\n  at System.Variant.GetValue () [0x0011e] in <084b4366b7b24485afe7dc701f3d4323>:0"...
0009:err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"DM: The host is not running a supported Windows operating system version."
^C002e:err:mscoree:expect_no_runtimes Process exited with a Mono runtime loaded.
```